# Dynamag USB card reader slow on keyboard mode in OSX

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks, credit-card, credit-card-track-data

My question is regarding credit card readers configured in Keyboard mode under OS X. I've noticed that the same reader running under OS X (I'm running 10.9.4, but the same holds true for previous versions) reads out swipe data about twice as fast in Windows 7 as it does on the Mac. For example, if I swipe a card using my MagTek Dynamag reader in to Text Edit (or any app) on the Mac, it can take a good 4-5 seconds to fully output the track data (the track is quite long because it's encrypted). If I run the same swipe using the same computer and reader using my VMWare Fusion Windows 7 virtual machine, the swipe outputs in a text file in about half the time (2-3 seconds). Even with whatever overhead is introduced by running a virtual machine, the output rate is still MUCH faster under Windows.

I originally just thought it was the reader that was slow until I tested it in Windows. Does anyone know what is causing the slower output rate on the Mac? Is it merely a setting or something more involved (such as USB drivers)? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Two guesses: either the device is doing deliberate pacing of its fake keystrokes to a rate somewhat credible for a typist (and for some reason doing that differently), or the operating system drivers are reading it in a different manner. It's very easy to write code which underutilizes the USB and accidentally introduces a drastic rate limit, by transferring only one character in each packet.  Using a USB analyzer could tell you a lot, if you can manage to get a software one in between the device and the OS driver.  Can you tell the OS to ignore it and use libusb directly instead?

Comment: Developer Tools has a usb analyzer, I'll give that a shot and see if I can determine anything.

Comment: Unfortunately I wasn't able to get much useful information from viewing the USB logger (at least not useful to me). Probably because I'm not all that knowledgable in the lower level stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this may be a combination of the OS USB drivers and the polling interval setting on the device. Some of the MagTek devices, Dynamag and IPAD included, have a polling interval setting which dictates how quickly the data is ouputted to ensure there is no "skipping" when the data is read.

Reference: 
[Dynamag Tech Reference](http://www.tempuspayment.com/documents/magtek_dynamag_tech.pdf) - actual page 8

"*Programmable USB Interrupt In Endpoint polling interval*"

[USB HID Swipe Reader](http://www.magtek.com/docs/99875191.pdf) - actual page19

"*The device has an adjustable endpoint descriptor
polling interval value that can be set to any value in the range of 1ms to 255ms. This property
can be used to speed up or slow down the card data transfer rate.*"

Comment: I appreciate your reply. It seems to indicate that the interval setting is a programmable function, I'll have to see if that's a possibility on my particular units. Do you think that would have varying impacts depending on the OS USB drivers? I find it odd that it operates at different speeds depending on the OS I'm testing on.

Comment: I want to say that I saw similar behavior a year+ ago with the IPAD's I was testing but not 100%. It is what prompted me to go searching for the setting I mentioned. I don't believe the speed is different on the device but the way the OS interprets it is. I will see if I can dig up my dynamag and Mac box to test.